# How to develop native ios app with existing Rails app as backend?

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a service which can let users create simple profiles.

It was made by reference to Ruby on Rails Tutorial(https://www.railstutorial.org/).

It can authenticate users simply with email and password.(without devise)

**Question:**

1. How to authorize users from ios in my Rails app?
2. How to post article to my Rails app from ios app?

**Environment:**

- Rails 4.2
- Swift 2.0

I would like to know the details of authentication flow and sample code.

Comment: You'll need to use an API on your Rails backend.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your users can auth by sending their email and password using a HTTP secure post request. The response would be a token that they can use for all future requests.
2. Your iOS app can make a secure HTTP POST to a resource like `/api/posts`. The API Posts controller would create a new `Post` from the params.